# StreamBuilder won't rebuild UI with sliverappbar

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I have the following code which runs normally.

```
class GroupPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String courseName;
  final String groupName;
  final String chatGroupidFromcollection;

  const GroupPage(
      {super.key,
      required this.courseName,
      required this.groupName,
      required this.chatGroupidFromcollection});

  @override
  State<GroupPage> createState() => _GroupPage();
}

class _GroupPage extends State<GroupPage> {
  //late Stream<StudyGroupModel?> _groupState;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //_groupState = FirestoreService.instance.documentStream(
    //path: FirestorePath.studyGroupswithid(
    //   widget.courseName, widget.groupName),
    // builder: (data) {
    //StudyGroupModel.fromSnap(data);
    // });
  }

  late Future<StudyGroupModel?> members =
      StudyGroupModel.fromId(widget.courseName, widget.groupName);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .doc(FirestorePath.studyGroupswithid(
                widget.courseName, widget.groupName))
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done &&
              (snapshot.hasData)) {
            debugPrint("Got rebuilt");
            return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.groupName)),
                body: DefaultTabController(
                  length: 3,
                  child: CustomScrollView(
                    slivers: [
                      SliverAppBar(
                        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                        elevation: 0,
                        pinned: false,
                        expandedHeight: 200,
                        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                            background: Stack(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: Container(
                                  decoration:
                                      const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red)),
                            ),
                            showJoinbutton(
                              groupfuture: members,
                              subchild: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                child: ElevatedButton(
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                      await FirestoreService.instance
                                          .updateDocument(
                                              path: FirestorePath
                                                  .studyGroupswithid(
                                                      widget.courseName,
                                                      widget.groupName),
                                              data: {
                                            'members': FieldValue.arrayUnion(
                                                [AuthMethods().uid])
                                          });
                                      await FirestoreService.instance
                                          .updateDocument(
                                        path: FirestorePath.chatGroup(
                                            widget.chatGroupidFromcollection),
                                        data: {
                                          'members.${AuthMethods().uid}': 0,
                                        },
                                      );
                                    },
                                    child: const Text("Join Group")),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        )),
                      ),
                      const SliverAppBar(
                          pinned: true,
                          primary: true,
                          elevation: 8.0,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                          title: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: TabBar(isScrollable: true, tabs: [
                                Tab(text: "Members"),
                                Tab(text: "Notes"),
                                Tab(text: "Group Chat")
                              ]))),
                      SliverFillRemaining(
                          child: SizedBox(
                              height: 500,
                              child: FutureBuilder(
                                  future: members,
                                  builder: (context,
                                      AsyncSnapshot<StudyGroupModel?>
                                          groupsnap) {
                                    if (groupsnap.hasData) {
                                      return TabBarView(children: [
                                        memberslist(members),
                                        const Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                                          child:
                                              Text("files display for viewing"),
                                        ),
                                        groupsnap.data!.members.length <= 1 &&
                                                (groupsnap
                                                        .data!.administrator ==
                                                    AuthMethods().uid)
                                            ? const Text(
                                                "More than one member has to be in the group for chat to be available")
                                            : !groupsnap.data!.members
                                                    .contains(AuthMethods().uid)
                                                ? const Text(
                                                    "Join Group to see group chat")
                                                : SizedBox(
                                                    height: 100,
                                                    child: memberslistforchat(
                                                        members,
                                                        widget.groupName))
                                      ]);
                                    } else if (groupsnap.hasError) {
                                      return const Text(
                                          "Some Error occurred when building the tabbar for studygroup future");
                                    } else {
                                      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                                    }
                                  })))
                    ],
                  ),
                ));
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          } else {
            return const Text("Error");
          }
        });
  }
}
```

What I am doing is having a group page, where users can join and administrator of group can kick users. If the user joins, the UI should remove the Join group button, if the Admin kicks the students, the UI should update to user as well.

Currently, I have a debugPrint, which prints "Got Rebuilt" every time a change occurs. If User joins, or administrator kicks him out, both times the debug console prints "Got Rebuilt". So it does work when receiving changes from the app, and from firebase. However the UI does not rebuild, I have to refresh the page for changes to be seen.

I also got an error saying Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget when opening the group page, but the UI does not reflect any errors. This errors occurs when the group page gets build initially and again when a change occurs. Help!

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem, showJoinbutton has a parameter members, which is a future. To rebuild it again, I just called setState and reassigned members value.

setState{() {
members = ....}}